# Grouping post conditions in a Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to group post conditions in a Jenkins declarative pipeline ?

For instance, I want to do the same thing for statuses `aborted` `failure` and `success`.
Is there a shorter way to do it than the following ?

```
post {
  aborted { sendNotification(currentBuild.result, "$LIST_NOTIFICATION_JENKINS") 
  failure { sendNotification(currentBuild.result, "$LIST_NOTIFICATION_JENKINS")     
  success { sendNotification(currentBuild.result, "$LIST_NOTIFICATION_JENKINS")
}
```

Comment: Having something like `aborted and failure and success { ... }` would be nice. Maybe such an extension of the DSL can be proposed by the community?

Answer (score 5):

There is the 'always' condition:

```
post {
  always {sendNotification(currentBuild.result, "$LIST_NOTIFICATION_JENKINS")}
}
```

The 'always' condition will run regardless of the stage result.

See the [documentation on the post section](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post).

If you want a set of common actions between just a few conditions, for example if you wanted to do the same thing for failure and aborted, I would recommend creating a function in your script to call from the failure and aborted post conditions.

You can also do something like the following:

```
always {
    script{
        if (currentBuild.currentResult == "ABORTED" || currentBuild.currentResult == "FAILURE")
        {
            echo "was aborted or failed"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess my example wasn't the best. I want to react to a combination of statuses, but not necessarily to all of them. Say, for instance, that I'd like to react to either  aborted or failure in the same way, without coding twice my function call.

Comment: You could try using an always post-condition and then within that using one or more of the following in an if statement: currentBuild.result, currentBuild.currentResult, currentBuild.resultIsBetterOrEqualTo, currentBuild.resultIsWorseOrEqualTo.