# Can I have a reusable "post" block for my jenkins pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have many jenkins pipelines for several different platforms but my "post{}" block for all those pipelines is pretty samey. And its quite large at this point because I include success,unstable,failure and aborted in it.

Is there a way to parameterize a reusable post{} block I can import in all my pipelines? I'd like to be able to import it and pass it params as well (because while its *almost* the same it varies very slightly for different pipelines).

Example post block that is currently copy and pasted inside all my pipeline{}s

```
post {
    success{
        script {
            // I'd like to be able to pass in values for param1 and param2
            someGroovyScript {
                param1 = 'blah1'
                param2 = 'blah2'
            }
            // maybe id want a conditional here that does something with a passed in param
            if (param3 == 'blah3') {
                echo 'doing something'
            }
        }
    }
    unstable{
        ... you get the idea
    }
    aborted{
        ... you get the idea
    }
    failure{
        ... you get the idea
    }
}
```

The following does not work:

// in mypipeline.groovy

```
...
post {
    script {
        myPost{}
    }
}
```

// in vars/myPost.groovy

```
def call(body) {

    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()

    return always {
        echo 'test'
    }
}
```

`Invalid condition "myPost" - valid conditions are [always, changed, fixed, regression, aborted, success, unstable, failure, notBuilt, cleanup]`

Can i override post{} somehow or something?

Comment: share your code, so we can comment on it. What you're asking about is doable for sure, but lets see which values are different and you want to parameterize.

Comment: added example post block

Comment: You can use a shared library for this.

Comment: what would a shared library look like for this? I want to use an actual post block- I know I can call an arbitrary groovy script but can I put a post{} block in that script?

Answer (score 2):

Shared libraries is one approach for this, you were pretty close.

```
@Library('my-shared-library')_
pipeline {
...
    post {
        always {
            script {
                myPost()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Answer based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/48563538/1783362
- Shared Libraries link: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: If you don't want to pass a parameter, simply use "someCoolThing()" and "def call(body)" instead.

Comment: This seems to be the best I've found so far, but it would involve having to implement our own status (success/unstable/failed/etc) checks. Any idea if we can pull out the entire post {} block into a shared library?

Comment: To my knowledge no. In the "our own status checks" it's really just a switch statement, and not much different in verbosity than the blocks. I'll agree the blocks make for nicer looking code, but at the end of the day...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking too; I don't want to replace our whole pipeline with [like they do here](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/10/02/pipeline-templates-with-shared-libraries/) so I may just switch to what you outlined. Cheers.

Comment: @joshft91 did you find a solution for the use case you mentioned ?

Comment: @cyberjoac - sorry for just seeing this. I eventually went with the route mentioned in this answer. I made it a one-liner like so: post { always { ourTeamPost() } } and then just implemented post actions in shared library. Hope that helps.

Comment: @joshft91thanks much, in the shared library could you use the declarative pipeline syntax ? Or does it have to be scripted syntax ? 
Because declarative handles conveniently the different states (regression, success, failure, aborted etc.)

Comment: @cyberjoac - another apology for the delay. Unfortunately I couldn't do it with declarative syntax. I created a ourTeamPost.groovy file in the /vars directory and then inside that implemented my own states (regression, success, etc) with an ENUM class and some logic to set the state. Based on those states I did certain things like sending emails. Hope this helps :)